# Undefined Symbol : ARAD1

Tags: assembly, tasm

I'm trying to use my own names for storing data, instead of ax,bx and so on. Is it even possible? If yes, how can I fix the undefined symbol error? Thanks.

Comment: You sure can: use a higher-level programming language.

Comment: Have you considered using a high-level language?

Comment: You can surely define labels for data locations.  You need to go away and learn some more about assemblers and CPU architectures before posting again.

Comment: ax and bx are registers and should be treated differently from named addresses or w/e you want to use. Different operations manipulate different registers and using aliases for them would just cause confusion.

Comment: I know higher level languages, I just want to study Assembly. What's so difficult to answer a simple question without raging on me like its madness that I dared posting it?

Comment: @Aradmey What does your assembly book says on this topic?

Comment: Look - you seem to be trying to learn assembler for a CPU architecture, (pretty clearly X86), that you don't understand.  That is not going to work.  At least Google it a bit.

Comment: @Aradmey: Are you talking about variables in memory, or about somehow renaming the registers? If you want to declare a variable, you can do so with the syntax supported by your assembler (e.g. `foo: db 0` in the `.data` section). Consult the assembler manual or google for more info. If you're talking about renaming registers then... why? You're just going to confuse yourself when reading the processor documentation.

Comment: I don't want to rename the registers, I want to define a new variable named 'ARAD1' so I can modify what is stored in it. Like 'MOV ARAD1, 3h' for instance. How can I do it with TASM?

Comment: You cannot do memory-to-memory transfers in x86.

Comment: [sigh] Google the following: 'x86 architecture and registers', 'x86 instruction set'.  Then look at some examples of x86 assembler code.  THEN try to code something.

Comment: @MartinJames: Well, `3h` is an immediate, so that would be a valid operand combination. @Aradmey: Like I said, use `ARAD1: db 0` or whatever your assembler supports. Try googling for "tasm declare variable". It can't be that hard to find example code for tasm.

Comment: @Michael - you sure?  8086 had only r/m = r, r = r/m ?

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is targeting something slightly newer than an 8086. That being said, even the 8086 supported `MOV mem, immed`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I use TASM and found the solution. All I used is dseg.

```
dseg    segment
    a DB 2 ; a is my newly variable (or array)
dseg    ends
cseg    segment
assume  cs:cseg, ds:dseg
     Start: mov ax, dseg
            mov ds, ax
            mov al, a
cseg ends
end Start
```

This is exactly how I did it and it works perfectly. DB is a keyword for defining a 8-bit variable. These are the keywords you can use:

```
Type |                   | Allocates          | Min-Max values                                                                            |
DB   | Define Byte       | allocates 1 byte   | 0 to 255 (or) -127 to 128                                                                 |
DW   | Define Word       | allocates 2 bytes  | 0 to 65535 (or) -32767 to 32768                                                           |
DD   | Define Doubleword | allocates 4 bytes  | 0 to 4294967295 (or) 2147483647 to 2147483648                                             |
DQ   | Define Quadword   | allocates 8 bytes  | 0 to 18446744073709551615 (or) -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775808                |
DT   | Define Ten Bytes  | allocates 10 bytes | 0 to 1208925819614629174706175 (or) -604462909807314587353087 to 604462909807314587353088 |
```

Hope I helped!!